# Can the domain also be referred to as the element of the set?

Tags: functions

I understand that the domain of a function is the set of all input values, but in some textbooks, the domain is an element of that  set of input values. How can a set also be a subset of that set?. This is what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but maybe this answers your question.

---

In ordinary set-theory it does not happen that a set (e.g. the domain of a function) is an element of itself.

What I did encounter for a function $f:X\to Y$ is the notation $f(X)$.

This however does not mean that $X$ must be looked in that context at as an input value for the function $f$, but is only a notation for the set: $$\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$$

This notation is used not only for $X$ itself but also subsets $A\subseteq X$:$$f(A):=\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}\subseteq Y$$

Comment: Maybe also mention it generalises to arbitrary subsets of X

Comment: @alkchf I followed your advice.